# Populating table B with data from table A if data in table B is different to table A

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, sql-insert

Apolgies for the confusing heading and long winded post.

I am attempting to populate an (Oracle) SQL table with data so I can monitor it on a regular basis and build up a picture of which users use which application modules.

I have a table 'forms_sessions_log' which was created as follows:

```
create table stuman.forms_sessions_log as (
select a.sid, a.serial#, a.logon_time, a.client_identifier,
a.module,a.username, a.SCHEMANAME, b.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, b.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME
from gv$session a, spriden b
where program like 'frmweb%'
and a.username=b.spriden_id)
```

This creates a 'snapshot' of 'forms' sessions connected to the database at that point in time.

From then on, each minute via a job scheduler, I'd like to continue to populate this table with any new or different sessions.

I came up with the following:

```
INSERT INTO stuman.forms_sessions_log
(sid,serial#,logon_time,client_identifier,module,username,SCHEMANAME,SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME,SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME)
SELECT  a.sid, 
        a.serial#, 
        a.logon_time, 
        a.client_identifier, 
        a.module , 
        a.username, 
        a.SCHEMANAME, 
        b.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
        b.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME
FROM    gv$session a 
        spriden b
WHERE       a.PROGRAM like 'frmweb%'
AND         a.username=b.spriden_id         
AND         NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM stuman.forms_sessions_log)
/
```

This didn't seem to work.  It failed to add any new sessions.  If I truncate the stuman.forms_sessions_log and run the insert statement again, it populates fine but then fails to add any new sessions to the table on consecutive attempts.

I looked at the code and decided to fine tune the statement using comparisons in the NOT EXISTS clause.

```
INSERT INTO stuman.forms_sessions_log
  (sid,serial#,logon_time,client_identifier,module,username,SCHEMANAME,SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME,SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME)
SELECT  a.sid, 
    a.serial#, 
    a.logon_time, 
    a.client_identifier, 
    a.module , 
    a.username, 
    a.SCHEMANAME, 
    b.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
    b.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME
FROM    gv$session a, 
        spriden b
WHERE       a.PROGRAM like 'frmweb%'
AND         a.username=b.spriden_id         
AND         NOT EXISTS(SELECT     a.sid,a.serial#,a.logon_time,a.client_identifier,a.module,a.username,a.SCHEMANAME 
            FROM stuman.forms_sessions_log a, 
                 gv$session b
        WHERE   a.sid=b.sid 
        AND     a.serial#=b.serial#
        AND     a.logon_time=b.logon_time
        AND     a.client_identifier=b.client_identifier
        AND     a.module=b.module 
        AND     a.username=b.username
        AND     a.SCHEMANAME=b.SCHEMANAME
                )
/
```

This also doesn't do what I was expecting.    I isolated the NOT EXISTS part of the query I wanted to check which is:

```
SELECT     a.sid,a.serial#,a.logon_time,a.client_identifier,a.module,a.username,a.SCHEMANAME 
            FROM stuman.forms_sessions_log a, 
                 gv$session b
        WHERE   a.sid=b.sid 
        AND     a.serial#=b.serial#
        AND     a.logon_time=b.logon_time
        AND     a.client_identifier=b.client_identifier
        AND     a.module=b.module 
        AND     a.username=b.username
        AND     a.SCHEMANAME=b.SCHEMANAME
```

Now, bear in mind that those defined fields in both table A and B are identical (stuman.forms_session_log was populated from gv$session), nothing returns.

I have one row stuman.forms_session_log which corresponds to a row in gv$session.

Why is the select statement above not returning any results?

Comment: Is this a MS SQL Server or Oracle issue? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: Sorry, I can't see an MSSQL server tag in my tag list

Comment: Oops, it was already removed by another user...

Comment: What is the PK on table forms_sessions_log ?

Comment: Doesn't that NOT EXISTS sub-query need a reference to one of the tables you select from? (As it is now, no row will be returned if stuman.forms_sessions_log contains any data, and no row if stuman.forms_sessions_log is empty.)

Comment: There's no PK on the forms_sessions_log table.   @jarlh - the way I'm reading that statement, I'm making sense of it in these terms:   select those columns from from_sessions_log where those specific columns in forms_sessions_log are the same as those in the gv$session table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to user MERGE?

```
MERGE INTO stuman.forms_sessions_log sl
USING (SELECT  a.sid, 
               a.serial#, 
               a.logon_time, 
               a.client_identifier, 
               a.module , 
               a.username, 
               a.SCHEMANAME, 
               b.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
               b.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME
       FROM    gv$session a, 
               spriden b
      WHERE    a.PROGRAM like 'frmweb%'
        AND    a.username=b.spriden_id  ) S
ON (    S.sid = SL.sid 
    AND S.serial# = sl.serial#)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (sid,serial#,logon_time,client_identifier,module,username,SCHEMANAME,SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME,SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME)
  VALUES (S.*)
```

Comment: Fantasic, this does exactly what was required.